# Base64 Decoded Password(Angular js) not working on server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I have an angular web app where I am trying to remember the username and password of the user on click of the checkbox . This is the code I am using

```
  var vm = this;

  if (rememberMeService('7ZXYZ@L') && rememberMeService('UU@#90')) 
  {
    vm.username = AuthenticationService.Base64.decode(rememberMeService('7ZXYZ@L'));
    vm.password = AuthenticationService.Base64.decode(rememberMeService('UU@#90'));
  }    

  vm.rememberMe = function () 
  {
    if (vm.remember) 
    {   
      rememberMeService('7ZXYZ@L', AuthenticationService.Base64.encode(vm.username));
      rememberMeService('UU@#90', AuthenticationService.Base64.encode(vm.password));
    } 
    else 
    {
      rememberMeService('7ZXYZ@L', '');
      rememberMeService('UU@#90', '');
    }
  }
```

This is the Html

```
<input data-ng-click="vm.rememberMe()" data-ng-model="vm.remember" name="remember" type="checkbox">   Remember Me
```

When I am trying to see the value in developer tools the value is the same as the password  that needs to be sent . But it is not validating on server side. But when I type the password again (the same password) then its validating on server side

Comment: Can you share server-side code, which is checking if the password is valid?

Comment: what is the library that you using?

Comment: @pes502 i do not have the server side code as it is being done by another team mate.

Comment: @Zamboney i am using my own Base64 code.. please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

may be try to call `$scope.$apply` `rememberMe` function